# Debugging angular-cli in WebStorm

Tags: debugging, phpstorm, webstorm, angular-cli

Using angular-cli starting project with WebStorm (PhpStorm).
I want to use debug - it seems to work but except it isn't :/

Here are some screen shots.

Here is mine first breakpoint
[image: Here is mine first breakpoint]

Next breakpoint
[image: Next breakpoint]

And my settings
[image: Settings]

Comment: recreated; however, this doesn't work for me in Chrome Dev Tools as well - I can't even create breakpoints where I like... for example, when I add breakpoint to `title = 'app works!';`, it's immediately moved to the line with class closing '}'; breakpoint in method call in constructor is actually created in the line with method return statement. So it seems that smth is wrong with either sourcemaps produced or V8 itself

Comment: I am having same problem.  debugging was working until i reached about 20 components.

Comment: I believe source maps generated by Angular CLI are not matchin with your original source code, maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54883663/706012

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed now with angular-cli beta19-3  (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1519). Please try updating;
As a workaround, you can edit `node_modules/angular-cli/models/webpack-build-development.js` by changing `cheap-module-source-map` to `source-map`