# Angular CLI 1.7.0 and Visual Studio Code - can't set breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio-code, angular-cli, breakpoints, chrome-debugging

I'm using the Chrome Debugger plugin in Visual Studio Code to debug an Angular application.  After upgrading to use angular/cli@1.7.0, we can no longer hit breakpoints in the typescript code within VS Code while debugging.  If we roll back to angular/cli@1.6.7, breakpoints start working again.

Here's my ng -v output:

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.0
Node: 9.2.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.7.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.1
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.1
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.1
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.0
@schematics/angular: 0.3.1
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.1
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.11.0
```

Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: There is an open issue, see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9729

Answer (score 12):

For those coming across this the fix is to modify your launch.json sourceMapPathOverrides as follows:

```
"sourceMapPathOverrides": { 
    "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*" 
}
```

This fixed it for me with the latest @angular/cli (version 1.7.3).

Answer was found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/issues/81).

Answer (score 7):

*Angular CLI 7.2.2*:

*Webstorm/Intellij* - breakpoints never hit, *VSCode* - breakpoints unverified/never hit, *Chrome debugger* - breakpoints hit perfectly.

**Solution:** in angular.json set evalSourceMap to "false".

[image: angular.json]

This triggers the Webpack that Angular CLI uses under the hood to generate source maps to original source code ("source-map") instead of generated code ("eval").  [https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/)

See under node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\browser.js

[image]

You can of course hack the browser.js file to set some other value for devtool.

Comment: Would you mind explaining a little further about how to hack the browser.js? I am trying to get debugging working in WebStorm but break points are not being hit.

Comment: @webworm Also with evalSourceMap=false in angular.json (in some versions angular-cli.json)? Then you have to find browser.js in your Angular CLI installation (for Angular CLI 7.2.2 it was: node_modules\angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\browser.js) and check how devtool/sourcemap is being set there. I just changed "eval" to "source-map" in the example above before I've found out where the buildOptions come from.

Comment: @angular/cli 10.2, `evalSourceMap` is not an allowed property

Answer (score 4):

Yes, same thing here.

Sometimes I can reach the breakpoint I want with some difficulty (the issue seems to be with the sourcemap, but the debugger is still functional).

I tried fiddling with some settings in the VS-Code debugger launch configuration ("sourceMaps" and "trace"), but to no avail.

Eventually I rolled back @angular/cli to 1.6.8 and it works fine again.

Edit:
Forgot to mention, in case it helps someone searching for this issue - when starting debugging, the breakpoints disappear from the source file and its tab is marked with "read-only inlined content from source map".

Also, @angular/cli 1.7.1 does not resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Same here, rolled back to 1.6.8 (and angular 5.1.1) to get my breakpoints working again.

Answer (score 1):

Setting **sourceMapPathOverrides** was not sufficient.

In my case the index.html file is located in "/src", and Angular components in  "/src/app". I use @angular/cli 1.7.4, vscode 1.22.2 and chrome debugger 4.3.0.

I had to set three parameters in the launch.json.

```
"sourceMapPathOverrides": { 
    "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*"
},
"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
"sourceMaps": true,
```

sourceMaps is optional but make sure it is not set to false.

It must be set for each configuration of the launch.json config file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Chrome DEBUG 172.22.44.49",
            ...
```

In the chrome debugger [sourcemaps documention](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug#sourcemaps), It is said to set webRoot to the directory that files are served from. But to solve this issue I had to set it to the workspace root directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a WorkSpace with 1 or more Projects..

Working for me:
launch.json

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "ng serve",
        "url": "http://localhost:4300",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/ProjectName",
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": { 
            "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*" 
        }
    }
]
```

1- Start Project ng serve --port 4300

2- Start Debugging