# Angular (ng test) Debugging - VS Code not stopping on Breakpoints

Tags: angular, debugging, visual-studio-code, karma-coverage

I am currently having a problem. I started writing Tests for my Angular application and wanted to debug them. Now I've googled alot, I tried the recipies from microsoft (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/Angular-CLI) and the closest I got to making it work was this BlogPost

http://blog.mlewandowski.com/Debugging-Karma-tests-with-VSCode.html

Now at least I can attach the Debugger to VS-Code. However VS Code does still not stop on Breakpoints, but the tests just continue to run. The Breakpoints in VS Code will also remain unverified (see image)

[image: Unverified Breakpoint]

This is what I have so far (I only supply the parts i have changed, to not post too much code).

Any Ideas what I am doing wrong? Apart from that debbuging works just fine. I can debug my node.js applications and debugging ng serve also works fine.

**launch.json**

```
{
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "MyApp - Tests",
    "address": "localhost",
    "port": 9222,
    "pathMapping": {
        "/": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "/base/": "${workspaceRoot}"
    }
}
```

**karma.conf.js**

```
browsers: [
    'ChromeDebugging'
],

customLaunchers: {
    ChromeDebugging: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--remote-debugging-port=9222']
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular CLI 1.7.0 and Visual Studio Code - can't set breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48892311/angular-cli-1-7-0-and-visual-studio-code-cant-set-breakpoints)

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed "Debugger for Chrome" extension.

Look at this guide.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/Angular-CLI

UPDATE:
This is my launch.json Maybe you can try it.

```js
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "ng serve",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200/#",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    {
      "name": "ng test",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:9876/debug.html",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    {
      "name": "ng e2e",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "args": ["${workspaceFolder}/e2e/protractor.conf.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Karma conf

```js
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Comment: See my first link ;) I tried that one too. But that didn't work at all. I couldn't even connect to the browser with that approach. Debugger for Chrome is installed. I use it to debug ng serve. Here it works fine

Comment: @relief.melone have you tried to run ng serve and dont stop it let it run. THen run the debugger

Comment: Yep. Tried it. Unfortunately no luck. I noticed the way that is described in the vscode-recipes is connecting but its still showing the same behavious as the attach command. So tests are running. But VS Code is not stopping on break points and lists them as unverified

Comment: @relief.melone out of curiosity, was it because your app was in a subfolder of your repository? In my case, I had to change the `webRoot` value inside the launch.json file. As follows: `"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/client"`. My app is inside a `client` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration, it attaches to a running `ng test` process with the port definded in your karma.conf.
If you have multiple browsers definde in your karma.conf, you might have to start ng test with `ng test --browser=ChromeDebugging`

```
{
        "name": "ng test",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "attach",
        "address": "localhost",
        "port": 9222,
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
            "/./*": "${webRoot}/*",
            "/src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
            "/*": "*",
            "/./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem recently in VSCode & Intellij, it has to do with source map generation in Webpack that Angular CLi uses under the hood. I fixed the problem by setting evalSourceMap: "false" in angular.json, see the complete answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54883663/706012.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add 'pathMapping' to launch.json as below:

```
{
        "name": "ng test",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://localhost:9876/debug.html",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "pathMapping": {
            "/_karma_webpack_": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
            "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*",
            "/./*": "${webRoot}/*",
            "/src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
            "/*": "*",
            "/./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
        }
    }
```